# Is there a way to give vertical space before the title of section when it is on the top of the page?

Tags: spacing, sectioning

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%twoside yaz iki taraflı için
\usepackage[top=2.5 cm, bottom=2.5 cm, left=4 cm, right=2.5 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{8 cm}{40pt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\section{hi}
Latex is the best 
\subsection{how are you?}
But sometimes it's hard 
\end{document}
```

I can manege to give splace after section title very easy with the command

```
 \titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{8 cm}{40pt}
```

{40 pt} for that purpose and work well but when section is top of beginning of the page {8 cm} do nothing.

Comment: Try \null\section{...}.  Generally people try to use less space, not more ;-)

Comment: Our school template likes that way. Thank you. Ona magical word saved me.